# Is there any way to add changes of record in frontend visible in typo3 be history?

Tags: typo3, typo3-8.x

I have frontend controller which can edit record in database. I want to know if there is any way to add information about that changes in typo3 backend history?[image]

I tried to use `typo3/cms/typo3/sysext/backend/Classes/History/RecordHistory.php`

I checked too how `typo3/cms/typo3/sysext/core/Classes/DataHandling/DataHandler.php` set it up but that was over complicated to do in frontend

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [`Packages/TYPO3.CMS/typo3/sysext/core/Classes/DataHandling/History/RecordHistoryStore.php`](https://github.com/TYPO3/TYPO3.CMS/blob/master/typo3/sysext/core/Classes/DataHandling/History/RecordHistoryStore.php):

you can use something similar when you are doing your edit operations.

First, create your own copy of the store as the class is internal and adjust it to your needs, then you can do something like:

```
$store = GeneralUtility::makeInstance(
        RecordHistoryStore::class,
        # or USER_FRONTEND depending on your use case
        RecordHistoryStore::USER_ANONYMOUS
    );
$store->addRecord($table, $uid, $payload);
```

Answer (score 2):

in TYPO3 V10 you can use this extension to make this easy. you just need to implement the interface provided by this extension with your Domain Models to make then trackable by history.
https://extensions.typo3.org/extension/fe_data_history/

Comment: i asked about typo3_8 but thanks for your answer, maybe will be helpful for someone :)